# % of Total in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table that has the following columns. I want to know what percentage of days had four or more published videos? What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
|  video_id  |  published_date  |
+------------+------------------+
|   abc      |     9/1/2018     |
|   dca      |     9/4/2018     |
|   5555     |     9/1/2018     |
```

Comment: Hello @Anna Chan, please can you tell us what database do you use ? Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server or something else ? Thanks!

Comment: Please format your data (as code?) so it's readable.  Provide more data.  Provide the expected output.

Comment: Percentage of all dates, whether there were any videos published or not, or percentage of dates when there were any videos published? And one way or the other, dates in what range? The last year, since the beginning of time, some other range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for Oracle: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=24e3fe791655d35e6f7564ef3a9986f8)

```
select sum(perc)  from (
select published_date
       , round(100*(count(*) / sum(count(*)) over ()),2) perc
       , count(published_date) cc
from dense_rank_demo
group by published_date)
where cc >= 4;
```

Here is the additional explanation for the OP's question in the comment: "Can you explain what this function is supposed to accomplish? SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()),2) perc"

1. First lets clean this question and say that the last part ",2)" is from ROUND function that rounds the decimal result in onl two decimals (that is why there is number 2).
2. The OVER part specifies the partitioning & ordering over which the analytic function operates. Because nothing is specified it will get a total sum of all records in combination with SUM(COUNT(*)).
3. I have added the additional select with some additional columns here: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a5270b3488a6275848c2e65a62449d34) that can help you little bit more to understand this SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()) part.
4. Down to numbers explanation "COUNT(*)" gives me a total count for every date because I have added this "group by published_date". That means it gives me 3 results in my example: 4, 4 and 3. SUM part of the command aggregates this like this: 4+4+3 and returns 11.

Solution for SQL Server: [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95325b843677324c3c950b3a7784b0ec)

```
select sum(perc) Perc  from (
select published_date
       , round(Count(published_date)* 100 / (Select Count(*) From dense_rank_demo), 2) perc
       , count(published_date) cc
from dense_rank_demo
group by published_date) t
where cc >= 4;
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Very helpful. Can you explain what this function is supposed to accomplish? SUM(COUNT(*)) over ()),2) perc

Comment: Hello @Anna Chan, I will explain, no poroblem. Please can you vote up this answer if it helped you? And also  if it is correct please mark it as corect. And one more thing, can you please confirm thatvyou use Oracle database? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @AnnaChan, thanks for marking it as correct. A vote up would be great :) Please, for other that might need help with simmilar things can yo uconfirm that you use Oracle ? I you do not know what do you use it is ok... I have added the explanation!

Comment: Thank you so much! very much appreciated!

Comment: i'd love to! but i just started on the platform and i dont have enough reputation points to upvote!

Comment: Ok :) Thanks for the answer.